# Create grid function makes QGIS crash

Tags: vector-grid

I am working with CSV point data set in QGIS. I have a world data set and I want to make a grid over it then to count the number of points per grid. But while executing the create grid function, QGIS does show processing window and crashed afterward. Also the system goes blank. So every time I have to shutdown the PC and starts again whenever I try to run create grid function. I am using EPSG 4326.

Following some suggestion to similar questions being asked already here, I did increase the dimensions of the grid cell and try to apply over small data set and over small grid extent. But the result was the same, crashing of QGIS then the PC.

[image: qgis crashed and PC go blank after this]

What should be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state what projection you are using. Global grids are notoriously hard to generate,  because the area of the cells is variable.

Comment: The extent and CRS do not match. Coordinates in EPSG:4326 are between -180/+180 and -90/+90 but your extent shows much bigger numbers.

Comment: @Vince I have edited the question by adding the CRS.

Comment: @user30184 I dont know how to make the extent shorter because i have the data in such extent.

Comment: Try to find out what is the correct CRS for your point data. The one who created the CSV should know the answer. When you know the source CRS you can re-project the data into EPSG:4326, and then create the grid if your aim is to have a global 1 by 1 degree sized grid for your analysis. If you aim at something else, please clarify it.

Comment: After importing CSV file, i saved it as shapefile and changed the crs to 4326. When trying with higher spacing, it gives me the grids as shown in the image in the answer below but for a dozen of points. Why its not giving grids for instance for whole data set with bigger grid cells? Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: Your current coordinates wrap around the globe 88784 times, east to west, and are all in some undefined place 53528745 degrees north of the North Pole.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate a gazillion grid cells, millions of millions.

Your data's CRS is not EPSG:4326 (geographic latitude and longitude) but something else. Once you fix that by assigning the correct CRS to your data you will realize that you did not try to generate one cell per actual 1° but one cell per (my reasonable guess) *meter*.

Then just choose a more reasonable grid cell size and it should work just fine.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to generate a grid cell of 3m by 3m for accuracy purposes. Now I have changed the CRS to EPSG 4326 but still the same problem

Comment: @SA_417 It is not reasonable to create a 3x3 meter *grid* to cover the globe. The Earth is 510072000 square kilometers. Even if it were topologically possible to generate 9m^2 square cells to cover an oblate spheroid, there would be 566746666666667 of them, and it would take the rest of your days to populate the table.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. I try to implement the suggestions of yours.